# Need checkbox change event to respond to change of checked state done programmatically

Tags: jquery

(jQuery 1.4.4) I have a checkbox that has a .change() listener that works fine for when the user clicks the checkbox, but now I also need it to fire when I programmatically change the checkbox in jQuery, using .attr('checked', 'checked').  I'm perfectly happy to use other methods to make this work.  Thanks.

```
$('#foo').attr('checked', 'checked'); // programmatically change the checkbox to checked, this checks the box alright

$('#foo').change( function() {
  // this works when user checks the box but not when the above code runs
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use jquery `click()` to change the state of the checkbox rather than changing its attribute.

Not having all your markup I'm not sure how suitable this would be, but I've used this method recently to good effect.

Comment: won't click() toggle the state?  I need to put the checkbox into the checked state regardless of its current state.

Comment: Yes it would, as I said it'd depend on your exact application as to it's suitability. You could detect it's state before running it, but I'm unclear as to the exact application.

Answer (score 25):

If you're using jQuery > 1.6, you can do this quite smartly by defining a `attrHook`;

```
jQuery.attrHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        if (el.checked !== value) {
            el.checked = value;
            $(el).trigger('change');
        }
    }
};
```

As pointed out in the comments, the `if` avoids a `change` event triggering if the new value is the same as the old value.

... Although really you should be using `prop()` anyway, so it should be;

```
jQuery.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        if (el.checked !== value) {
            el.checked = value;
            $(el).trigger('change');
        }
    }
};
```

You can see this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/2nKPY/

For jQuery < 1.6 (or if you don't fancy adding a `propHook`) the best you can do is override the `attr()` method (or upgrade :));

```
(function () {
    var existingAttr = jQuery.fn.attr;

    jQuery.fn.attr = function (attr) {
        var result = existingAttr.apply(this, arguments);

        if (result instanceof jQuery && attr == "checked") { // If we're dealing with a check-set operation.
            result.trigger('change');
        }

        return this;
    };    

}());
```

[You can see this in operation here](http://jsfiddle.net/2nKPY/1/)

Comment: That's great! Too bad it does not work for my problem (I'm using knockout, which does not set the attribute with jquery). Might be useful in the future anyway

Answer (score 16):

How about:

```
$('some selector').trigger('click');
```

Comment: This is the best option IMO. Simple, clean, and localized. Unlike the click() this doesn't have any weird side effects like changing the state of the dom.

Answer (score 4):

This will only trigger when the value of checked actually changes. In Matt's answer it will trigger even if same value is assigned to checkbox.

```
$.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        if (el.checked !== value) {
            trigger = true;
        } else {
            trigger = false;
        }
        el.checked = value;
        if (trigger) {
            $(el).trigger('change');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a plugin that swaps images based on the state of a checkbox, and I ran across this issue too.

To complicate matters for me, a lot of the pre-existing code I'm working with (working *around*? ;)) expects change events to come from user-interaction *only*, so triggering a click() when the checkbox should be ***programmatically*** checked/unchecked causes other events to fire that *shouldn't* (these other handlers should only run when the **user** changes the value).

The solution I settled on was to bind my image-update handler to both the "change" event *and* a custom event that I called "updateicon". Then, in `propHooks.checked.set()`, I trigger this "updateicon" event. This causes the icon-updater to change the icon in the same way as when a user clicks the input, but does *not* cause the previously-bound change/click-handlers to misfire.

*Event handler binding:*

```
input.on("change updateicon", toggleIconVisibility);
```

*Property change hook:*

```
jQuery.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        el.checked = value;
        $(el).trigger('updateicon');
    }
};
```

*Note: In my latest draft of the code, I run $(el).filter(".iconified").trigger("updateicon"), so as to only trigger "updateicon" on the elements that were "iconified" by my plugin*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relatively new version of JQuery, you may use the .prop() function to programmically change the checkbox:

```
$(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
$(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: That still doesn't fire a change event - you'll need to use `$(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");` or use Matts code with the attrhooks