# How to use propHooks in an unobtrusive way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to fix a [small jQuery plugin](https://github.com/itsalif/ezMark) which turns an HTML checkbox into a graphical one. The problem I'm facing is that if I change the "checked" property on the checkbox, the `change` event doesn't get triggered, and therefore the graphical represntation doesn't get updated.

Obviously, I can just trigger the change event manually when I change the property, but I'd like to find a more general solution that will be contained within the plugin.

Searching around, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392279/7581), which pointed me towards propHooks, which I can use to get notified whenever a property gets set. So I can write this:

```
jQuery.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        el.checked = value;
        $(el).trigger('change');
    }
};
```

And now the change event gets triggered whenever the property gets set.

My concern is, that this is not very localized. Now I've changed the way jQuery behaves for everything on the page, just for the sake of this small plugin. Futhermore, I'm not sure what happens if two plugins on the page happen to use the same technique. Will the event get triggered twice, or will the second hook overwrite the first? Either behavior seems problematic.

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation of propHooks. What's the proper way to use it?

Comment: I think this question may *be* the documentation for propHooks...

Answer (score 2):

*SIGH.*

I was hoping for someone to shed a light on the reasoning behind the way propHooks works. Anyway, here's what I did to limit the effect of propHooks to the plugin.

I added the following code to the plugin itself:

```
var $elements = $();

$.fn.ezmark = function(options) {
    ...
    return this.each(function() {
        ... // plugin code

        // Make a list of all elements that the plugin was applied to
        $elements = $elements.add(this);
    });
}
```

And then in the propHooks code, I checked if the element in question is on the list, like this:

```
$.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        if ($elements.filter(el).length !== 0) {
            el.checked = value;
            $(el).trigger('change');
        }
    }
};
```

This is far from perfect. I probably could make it even less obtrusive by not triggerring the event, but instead just calling the plugin handler for a state change.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a similar plugin and ran across this issue too.

A lot of the pre-existing code I'm working with expects change events to come from user-interaction **only**, so triggering a "change" event when the checkbox is **programmatically** checked/unchecked causes other events to fire that shouldn't (these other handlers should only run when the **user** changes the value).

The solution I settled on was to bind my icon-update-handler to both the "change" event, **and** a custom event that I called "updateicon". Then, in propHooks.checked.set(), I trigger this "updateicon" event only if the element that was checked/unchecked has the class that my plugin uses to find and bind these "iconified" input/checkbox elements.

```
jQuery.propHooks.checked = {
    set: function (el, value) {
        el.checked = value;
        var jqEl = $(el);
        if(jqEl.is(".iconified")) jqEl.trigger('updateicon');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't effect to the default behavior of native checkbox.

```
 jQuery.propHooks.checked = {
   get: function (el) {
     if $(el).is(':checkbox') {
       return null;                // should not return undefined, return null.
     }
     // do something
   },
   set: function (el, value) {
     if $(el).is(':checkbox') {
       return undefined;           // should not return null, return undefined.
     }
     // do something
   }
 };
```

Related code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L400-L409

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're addressing a separate issue which could be described as **"How to add propHooks while also keeping the default behavior?"**. Am I right?