# Checkbox check from cookie in a dynamically created checkbox array (jquery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

Many thanks for reading.
I have a paged dataset (created from SPRY XML Dataset) spanned in multiple pages.
I use jquery cookies  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to save which checkboxes are checked since the checked checkboxes were lost between pages. I have used 
the following code to set the cookies (from a stackoverflow post)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // find the div named books containg rows and a checkbox in the end
    $("#books").on("click",function(){



    $(":checkbox:checked.chkbCsm").each(function() {//alert("test");
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('value'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
    }
});

$(":checkbox:checked.chkbCsm").change(function() {


    $.cookie($(this).attr("value"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    })
});


});
```

wraped within  .on since the table is created dynamically. The cookies are set correctly.

I have created the following snippet to restore the checkboxes by reading the values from 
the cookies array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var cookies = get_cookies_array();
var temp = [];

// keep only cookies relevant in temp
for( var name in cookies) {

  if (!isNaN(name) && cookies[name]=="true") {

    temp.push(name);

 }

}

//restore all cookies from temp array   
    for( i=0 ; i<temp.length ; i++) {


var text=temp[i];
$('input[value='+text+']').prop('checked', true);
}


});//document ready
```

Code works generally but there is a problem.
Assume a checkbox is checked the cookie is set and then you move to the next page and then
you move back.
The cookie restores the checkbox correctly. But if you uncheck the 
checkbox the click is ignored and the cookie is still consider to contain a checked checkbox.
If you repeat check uncheck again then the cookie is correctly set to false (i.e. uncheck).
That means, probably, that the first time .change() function is not triggered which is definitely unwanted.
In addition I understand that if the 
checkbox is changed state programmatically .change() is not triggered.
I have tried several routes (put .triggerHandler("change"); next to .prop() ) 
and studied [Need checkbox change event to respond to change of checked state done programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392192/need-checkbox-change-event-to-respond-to-change-of-checked-state-done-programmat) and [Why isn't my checkbox change event triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869981/why-isnt-my-checkbox-change-event-triggered) but did not solved my problem.

Any ideas welcome how to fix this.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone interested , the problem seems to be solved (at least in Firefox ...) by adding a .trigger("click") after updating the dataset paged region (i have included the Spry Observer details) i.e.

```
myObserver = new Object;
myObserver.onPostUpdate = function(notifier, data)
{       
    $(document).ready(function() {

var cookies = get_cookies_array();
var temp = [];

for( var name in cookies) {

  if (!isNaN(name) && cookies[name]=="true") {

    temp.push(name);
 }

}
    for( i=0 ; i<temp.length ; i++) {
var text=temp[i];
$('input[value='+text+']').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler("change");
}

});//document ready

$(document).ready(function() {
**$("#books").trigger("click");**
});
};



Spry.Data.Region.addObserver("bibliapv", myObserver);
```

It appears that for some reason  the first click after the navigation between the dataset pages in an already checked checkbox was  missed.  Many thanks again for reading.