# How to test React component asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mocha.js

I have a component with a method bind to `onChange` event of its child component. In a nutshell:

```
DOM = React.DOM

Range = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    isRange: false

  render: ->
    check = DOM.input
      type: "checkbox",
      onChange: @rangeChanged,
      checked: @state.isRange
      name: "isRange"
    DOM.form {}, [check]

  rangeChanged: React.autoBind ->
    @setState
      isRange: !@state.isRange
```

During a test, I want to change the value of the checkbox and trigger `change` event.
My test looks like (using mocha.js + expect.js):

```
root = $("#root")

describe "test Range", ->
  beforeEach ->
    @range = Range()
    React.renderComponent(@range, root[0])

  afterEach ->
    React.unmountAndReleaseReactRootNode(root[0])

  it "should run event", (done) ->
    r = root.find("input[name=isRange]").prop("checked", true).trigger('change')
    setTimeout (=> expect(@range.state.isRange).to.be.true; done()), 10
```

Unfortunately, I can't get any solution to make this test working. Any idea how to make it work?

[jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/robert_zaremba/LWXhs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this out there so that everyone can see.

[Need checkbox change event to respond to change of checked state done programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392192/need-checkbox-change-event-to-respond-to-change-of-checked-state-done-programmat)

Basically, the problem is that jQuery uses `trigger('click')` rather than `change` to actually change the checkbox's state. `change` in this case is just like another custom event you don't want.